# android weight sum

Tags: android

i have defined weightsum for one 1 tablerow and layout_weight. this is what i am doing

```
 <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="1" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/add"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:text="@string/restaurant_add"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Restaurant_add"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:clickable="true" />
        </TableRow>
```

i am filling the data to Restaurant_add dynamically.. but when i fill the data to Restauant_add, even though i have set the layout_weight to 0.8, it is overriding the data present in  android:text="@string/restaurant_add".

what is the mistake i am doing?

Thanks:)

Comment: can you post a screen shot of how it looks?

Comment: @FoamyGuy how will i post screen shot here?

Comment: When you edit your post, one of the buttons along the top of the editing box is insert image. If you don't have that option (you may not have enough rep) then just paste a link to imgur or some other image host and someone will edit it into an image for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to set `android:layout_width="0dp"` to your two TextView ?

Also, your TextView's id Restaurant_add is the same as your string @string/restaurant_add. Make sure that you modify the layout and not your string !

Comment: In this case, fill_parent and 0dp give the same result, only that 0dp gives better performance.

Comment: Ok. I've edit my comment, be sure to modify your layout Restaurant_add and not you string restaurant_add.

Comment: @Damien thnx:) i modified the proper one only and i got the result i wanted. but can i know how it worked and what was my mistake?.

Comment: Are you talking about layout_width or Restaurant_add ids ? :)

Comment: Well, when you want to use layout_weight, you must tell android which dimension it has to scale (height or width).

But in your previous code, fill parent means "i want you to take all the width of your parent", in this case, your TableRow's width.

So to let android know which dimension it has to scale (80%/20% in your case) your must set your dimension to 0dp.
More infos [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_weight)

Answer (score 0):

Set both your android:layout_widths to "0dp".